# libCordova.a missing from custom build scheme in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, clang

I have a Cordova 3.4 project that I'm trying to archive and build an ipa but I'm getting error. I created a couple of custom schemes and configurations to test the app against our dev api server. I have a scheme named SchemeReleaseDevServer that points to our dev server but it won't build. I'm getting an error that it can't find libCordova.a. I'm hoping this is just a simply config fix. I know enough to be dangerous with this.   Here's the log:

```
Ld /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/APPNAME.app/APPNAME normal armv7
cd /Users/jdoe/beanstalk/myapp/Cordova/platforms/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/BuildProductsPath/Release\ DevAPI-iphoneos -LAPPNAME/Plugins -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.domain.cordova.ar -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.domain.cordova.buildinfo -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.domain.cordova.inappbrowser -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.domain.cordova.pdfviewer -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.domain.cordova.progresshud -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.domain.cordova.pushnotification -LAPPNAME/Plugins/com.testflightapp.cordova-plugin -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.battery-status -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.console -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-motion -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-orientation -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.file -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.globalization -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.media -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar -LAPPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.vibration -L/Users/jdoe/beanstalk/myapp/Cordova/platforms/ios/Libraries -F/Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/BuildProductsPath/Release\ DevAPI-iphoneos -filelist /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/APPNAME.build/Release\ DevAPI-iphoneos/APPNAME.build/Objects-normal/armv7/APPNAME.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -all_load /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/BuildProductsPath/Release\ DevAPI-iphoneos/libCordova.a -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.1.1 -lz -lTestFlight -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework GameKit -framework iAd -liconv -framework MediaPlayer -weak_framework AddressBook -weak_framework AddressBookUI -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework ImageIO -framework MessageUI -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a /Users/jdoe/beanstalk/myapp/Cordova/platforms/ios/APPNAME/Plugins/com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin/GoogleAnalytics.a -framework SystemConfiguration -lQCAR -liPhone-lib -lQCARUnityPlayer -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/APPNAME.build/Release\ DevAPI-iphoneos/APPNAME.build/Objects-normal/armv7/APPNAME_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/APPNAME.app/APPNAME

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-dwizlmxzqlhfpvfknnwmxenlpnbm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SchemeReleaseDevServer/BuildProductsPath/Release DevAPI-iphoneos/libCordova.a'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs across this, I solved the issue by changing the 'Build Locations' section as shown $BUILD_DIR for my CordovaLib.xcodeproj (both target & project). Not sure if there are any implications for the change but I'm able to build now.

[image: Project]

[image: Target]

Answer (score 0):

Cordova 3.4 is not exactly compatible with XCode 5.1.. [This post](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/) explains the changes that you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `link with libraries` in `build phases`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `cordova prepare ios` before trying `cordova build ios`

This will generate libcordova.a